# How to extract attribute and value from XML inside a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have written the following XML, which allows me to extract data values from a Visual Studio Resources.resx file where the name contains a certain value:

```
Select-Xml -XPath '//data[contains(@name,''QIM'')]/value' -Path 'Resources.resx' | Select-Object -Expand Node | Select-Object -Expand '#text'
```

How can I expand this Powershell script to add the name attribute as a heading (ideally surrounded by some characters like ** to identify it as a heading) before each set of text in the resulting file - this is for a diff to allow an email notification of changes, so any suggestions that would allow it to be diffed against an existing file are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which provides the results as `[pscustomobject]` instances, which results in a two-column tabular display:

```
Select-Xml -XPath '//data[contains(@name,''QIM'')]' -Path 'Resources.resx' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      NameAttributeValue = $_.Node.name
      ElementText = $_.Node.value
    }
  }
```

The output will be something like this:

```
NameAttributeValue ElementText
------------------ -----------
foo QIM            some text
bar QIM            some other text
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks, but my elements are very long and this seems to truncate after 30 characters - is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Thomas, the truncation is merely a _display artifact_ - the data is all there. If you want to send this _for-display_ representation to a file, use `Out-File` with the `-Width` parameter with a large enough value to avoid the truncation (in Windows PowerShell, be careful with large values, because all lines get _padded_ to that length). However, consider using a _structured_ text format to save the results, such as CSV, using [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)